# SonicMQ queue not found

Tags: java, jms, sonicmq

I am working on a JMS subscriber application in which i need to connect to a remote SonicMQ queue. When i connect to the queue using broker url,username,password etc, I am getting Queue not found exception but the queue exists on the broker and queue details are available on the .binding file. So can all the queues available in the .binding file be accessed using the non-.binding file method(connecting to broker using broker url and port)? Is there any difference between connecting to the broker using the brokerurl,username,password etc and connecting using .binding file as a provider url?

Comment: Please consider improving the readability of your question. Like using paragraphs, and not having sentences spawn several lines.

Comment: Please add more information like extract of the code? What do you call a .binding file. Try to hard-code your queue name first. Are you sure it is not using JNDI?